# How to configure celery schedule crontab in python to execute the task from 2pm to 9am, every hour?

Tags: python, cron, celery

I tried it like this:

```
crontab(hour="14-9")
```

but it doesn't work. It executes it continuously; as soon as the task ends, it repeats immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official celery docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html?highlight=cron#crontab-schedules) you have to add *minute=0* attribute to your crontab call.

Your code has to be like:

```
crontab(hour="14-9", minute=0)
```